# Extjs4 Grid is loading 3 times after adding remoteFilter to store

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I am using ExtJs 4.2.1 version. My grid is loading 3 times after I adding `remoteFilter` to `true` in `store`.

```
Ext.define('PM.store.Orgs', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'PM.model.org',
    autoLoad: false,
    remoteFilter: true,
    sorters: ['orgId'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: { read: 'api/org/findByOrgId' },
        reader: { type: 'json' }
    }
});
```

After adding `remoteFilter:true`, it was loading 3 times.

Comment: Could you show some code?

Comment: Ext.define('PM.store.Orgs', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'PM.model.org',
    autoLoad: false,
    remoteFilter: true,     
    sorters: ['orgId'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
         read: 'api/org/findByOrgId'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    },
 
});

After adding remoteFilter:true ,it was loading 3 times.
Please help

Comment: `autoLoad: false,`: where/when do call call the load() function? You could trace the loading (listeners: load: function() {add your tracing here}) in order to know if it is actually loaded 3 times

Answer (score 0):

Without making any changes to my code ,now it is loading only once.Seems very weird behaviour.
   Actually I wanted to apply remote filter feature to grid.However I was able to do it by making local flag to false in grid and without adding remote Filter flag to store. 
   Thank you